# Disable 2.4GHz WiFi on Android

Tags: wi-fi, android-14

I've seen [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197064/prefer-5ghz-over-2-4ghz-without-disabling-2-4ghz). It's not very useful to me, because I don't have control over my router.

Notably, 2.4GHz and 5.0GHz have the same name on my network. If I had control over the router, I would create a 5GHz network, and a 2.4 GHz network, and tell my phone to only connect to the 5GHz one. I don't have this luxury, so I want to disable 2.4GHz at the device level.

I find that my phone will connect to 2.4GHz WiFi despite it being substantially slower. This is not just theoretically, but in practice: where I am in the house, 2.4GHz has been consistently slower, 3-5 times slower. On my Windows PC, I can change my network adapter settings so it only connects to the 5GHz network, so I know this should be possible. Is there a way on Android 14 to disable 2.4GHz WiFi?